# Better way to setup graceful shutdown with Akka Streams

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I have pretty simple application that has an Akka HTTP endpoint, does some processing and writes results to either of the output files. The code to ensure graceful shutdown looks a bit complicated, is there a way to make it more succinct?

```
  val bindingFuture = Http().newServerAt("localhost", config.port).bind(route)

  val validQueue: BoundedSourceQueue[ByteString] = ???
  val invalidQueue: BoundedSourceQueue[ByteString] = ???
  val validDone: Future[Done] = ???
  val invalidDone: Future[Done] = ???
  val allDone = Future.sequence(validDone, invalidDone)

  bindingFuture.onComplete {
    case Success(binding) =>
      logger.info("Server started on port {}", config.port)
      binding.addToCoordinatedShutdown(5.seconds)
    case Failure(ex) =>
      logger.error("Can't start server", ex)
      system.terminate()
  }

  allDone.onComplete { result =>
    result match {
      case Failure(ex) =>
        logger.error("Streams completed with error", ex)
      case Success(_) =>
        logger.info("Streams completed successfully")
    }
    system.terminate()
  }

  sys.addShutdownHook {
    logger.info("Shutting down...")
    validQueue.complete()
    invalidQueue.complete()
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Akka installs JVM shutdown hooks by default, there is no need to add a shutdown hook yourself, you can remove `sys.addShutdownHook { ... }`
Calling `ActorSystem.terminate` will also terminate all streams. (Streams can be terminated abruptly, in most applications this is not a problem though, and it sounds like this would also not be a problem in your case.)

Minor cleanup, you could consider using `map`, `recoverWith` and `andThen`.

```scala
allDone.map { _ =>
  logger.info("Streams completed successfully")
}.recoverWith {
  case ex => 
    logger.error("Streams completed with error", ex)
}.andThen {
  case _ => system.terminate()
}
```

You could use CoordinatedShutdown:

```scala
CoordinatedShutdown(context.system).addTask(CoordinatedShutdown.PhaseServiceRequestsDone, "complete hdfs sinks") { () =>
    validQueue.complete()
    invalidQueue.complete()
  }
```

You could also use a shared kill switch (https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-dynamic.html#sharedkillswitch), which you can put in your flows with `.via(sharedKillSwitch.flow)`, you could shutdown the switch from the CoordinatedShutdown:

```scala
// create it somewhere, use in your flows
val sharedKillSwitch = KillSwitches.shared("hdfs-switch")

// use switch in CoordinatedShutdown
CoordinatedShutdown(context.system).addTask(CoordinatedShutdown.PhaseServiceRequestsDone, "complete hdfs sinks") { () =>
    sharedKillSwitch.shutdown()
  }
```

Comment: In my case it's actually important to gracefully shutdown sinks (they are Alpakka HDFS sinks) that write files, otherwise last file isn't actually written.

Comment: You could use CoordinatedShutdown instead of the `addShutdownHook` and complete the streams, possibly using `PhaseServiceRequestsDone` to wait for requests that are in progress to be completed. Did you check out https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/coordinated-shutdown.html?

Comment: Added some details on how to do that.